# Change behaviour of gallery slider

Tags: javascript, slider, gallery, swiper.js

I just started getting into development. I’m trying to adjust a slider from a library (https://swiperjs.com) to better suit my page. By default it comes with arrows on the left and right, to trigger the slider to move..

Now I’d like to change it so the slider advances forward everytime a user clicks anywhere on the image area.

What I have so far:

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                // parameters
                direction: 'horizontal',
                loop: true,

                // pagination
                pagination: {
                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                },

                // navigation
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                },
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="source/promo_1.png" alt="promo-1" class="image"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="source/promo_2.png" alt="promo-2" class="image"></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"> <img src="source/promo_3.png" alt="promo-3" class="image"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
```

Any idea how I can achieve this? Does it even make sense to overwrite the behaviour of the library or should I look for an alternative? The whole library thing is a bit of a blackbox to me.

Many thanks!